# Adding elements from html input using javascript and adding/deleting lines to html

Tags: javascript, arrays, addition

I have a section of code that I'm struggling with. I'm adding more lines to a table when the user clicks the [ + ]. Javascript for that part is working. Each line has 5 values that I would like to add together and put in an input field on each line. I have had a little success getting the first line to add to the qty input box, but not additional lines added.

In addition, when the user clicks the [ - ] to remove not all the line is removed.

I have similar code working in other parts of the project, but this one is by far more complicated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Workorder</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/workorder.css" />
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        td, th { border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 2px; vertical-align: top; }
        * { box-sizing: border-box; }
        .wrapper { max-width: 500px; margin: 2px auto;  }
        .wrapper > div { border: 1px solid #aaa; border-radius: 2px; background-color: #eee; padding: 0; color: #000; }
        .wrapper { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); grid-gap: 2px; grid-auto-rows: minmax(30px, auto);  }
        .g-po   { grid-column: 1/5;  grid-row: 1; }
        .g-submit { grid-column: 1/5;  grid-row: 2; }
        .button { font-size: 18px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="center">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="PO" id="PO" action="writePO.php" onsubmit="return validateIndex()">
<!-- *** body ********************************************* -->
                <table id="tablePO">
                    <tr>
                        <th>QTY Ordered</th>
                        <th colspan="6"> Description </th>
                        <th>FOR:</th>
                        <th>Work Order #</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="qtyOrdered[]" id="qtyOrdered" size="3" value="0" /></td>
                        <td colspan="6"><input type="text" name="Description[]" id="Description" value="" size="25" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="for[]" id="for" value="" size="18" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="workorder[]" id="workorder" value="" size="8" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <th>YS</th>
                        <th>YM</th>
                        <th>YL</th>
                        <th>YXL</th>
                        <th><input type="text" name="otherSize[]" size="1" placeholder="other" /></th>
                        <td rowspan="2"><input type="button" class="add_PO" value="+" /></td>
                        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="YS[]" id="YS" size="1" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="YM[]" id="YM" size="1" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="YL[]" id="YL" size="1" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="YXL[]" id="YXL" size="1" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="otherSizeQty[]" id="otherSizeQty" size="1" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        <table><tr><td><input type="submit" formmethod="post" class="button[]" value="Submit" /></td></tr></table>
    </form>    

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var lineCount = 1;
        $('body').on('click','#tablePO .del_PO',function(){
            lineCount = lineCount - 1;
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
        $('body').on('click','#tablePO .add_PO',function(){
            $(this).val('-');
            $(this).attr('class','del_PO');                var appendTxt;
            appendTxt += "<tr>\n";
            appendTxt += "    <td><input type='text' name='qtyOrdered[]' id='qtyOrdered' size='3' value='0' /></td>\n";
            appendTxt += "    <td colspan='6'><input type='text' name='Description[]' id='Description' value='' size='25' /></td>\n";
            appendTxt += "    <td><input type='text' name='for[]' id='for' value='' size='18' /></td>\n";
            appendTxt += "    <td><input type='text' name='workorder[]' id='workorder' value='' size='8' /></td>\n";
            appendTxt += "</tr>\n";
            appendTxt += "<tr>\n";
            appendTxt += "    <td rowspan='2'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>\n";
            appendTxt += "    <th>YS</th>\n";
            appendTxt += "    <th>YM</th>\n";
            appendTxt += "    <th>YL</th>\n";
            appendTxt += "    <th>YXL</th>\n";
            appendTxt += "    <th><input type='text' name='otherSize[]' size='1' placeholder='other' /></th>\n";
            appendTxt += "    <td rowspan='2'><input type='button' class='add_PO' value='+' /></td>\n";
            appendTxt += "    <td rowspan='2'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>\n";
            appendTxt += "    <td rowspan='2'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>\n";
            appendTxt += "</tr>\n";
            appendTxt += "<tr>\n";
            appendTxt += "    <td><input type='text' name='YS[]' id='YS' size='1' /></td>\n";
            appendTxt += "    <td><input type='text' name='YM[]' id='YM' size='1' /></td>\n";
            appendTxt += "    <td><input type='text' name='YL[]' id='YL' size='1' /></td>\n";
            appendTxt += "    <td><input type='text' name='YXL[]' id='YXL' size='1' /></td>\n";
            appendTxt += "    <td><input type='text' name='otherSizeQty[]' id='otherSizeQty' size='1' /></td>\n";
            appendTxt += "</tr>\n";
            $("#tablePO tr:last").after(appendTxt); 

            var YS = Number(document.getElementById("YS").value);
            var YM = Number(document.getElementById("YM").value);
            var YL = Number(document.getElementById("YL").value);
            var YXL = Number(document.getElementById("YXL").value);
            var otherSizeQty = Number(document.getElementById("otherSizeQty").value);
            var totQty = document.getElementById("qtyOrdered");
            var totOrdered = YS + YM + YL + YXL + otherSizeQty;
            totQty.value = totOrdered;
            lineCount = lineCount + 1;
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Alisa

Comment: Please add relevant code here to be checked.

Comment: Anurag, I added the code.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: started from scratch, ran it at localhost, and checked for js errors. Sgould run now. Sorry it took so long to get it right.